# SQL - get specific dates based on working week

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dateadd, datepart

We need to determine specific dates between which data would be extracted.

For example, transactions that take place on the first of the month are posted to the accounting system on the 2nd, and transactions that take place on the last day of the month are posted to the accounting system on the 1st of the following month.

So whereas normally I could just take all records where the month is 10 for October, now I need to extract records where the date is between the 2nd of October and before the 2nd of November.

I have the below code to get the earliest date (doesn't matter if it's a weekend as in that case the records will show a posting date for the first working day after the weekend):

```
Declare @EarliestDate varchar(8), @SQL NVARCHAR(1000), @sDate varchar(8)

-- get data for the last 3 months
SET @EarliestDate= CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(m,-3, getdate())) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
    + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(m,-2, getdate())) AS varchar(2)), 2)+ '02'
```

Now I need to check if the 1st of November is a weekend, and if it is, use the date of the next Monday.

I have started the below code but I cannot get it to work properly:

```
Declare @LatestDate datetime

set @LatestDate = '01/11/2014'

if datepart(dw,@LatestDate) in (1,7)
Begin
    set @LatestDate = DATEADD(d,1,@LatestDate ) 
End
```

Please can you show me where I am going wrong? Ideally it should work all the year round regardless of what the year is, always getting the first working day after the 1st of the month.

Comment: If it's an option, you may want to consider adding a new metadata column that is populated via trigger, then just query off of that column. It seems like there more business logic at play than you're even aware of. Are holidays an issue?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: yes, I have just been reminded that Holidays will indeed be an issue, so will have to consider checking if the date is in the Holidays table as well...

Comment: I can almost guarantee you that someone else, someday, is going to need to query based on the Post_Date as well. This really feels like an additional column that should be filled in by the application, or by a trigger that runs on row insert/update.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: well it's for an SSRS report, so I will give the users the option to type in the date range, but if they don't enter the date range (for example, for scheduled execution) then it would always be the months data from the 1st working day after the first until the 1st working day of the following month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you generate the Date table from the script at 
[Create and Populate at Date Dimension for Data Warehouse](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho) and use that to figure out when your next workday is.  For my own purposes I dropped all the UK columns and Fiscal columns - though they maybe useful to you.  You can also add your own Holidays too, and join directly in a query instead of creating a specific function.

Then you can just do the following:

```
DECLARE @LatestDate date

SET @LatestDate = '01/11/2014'

SELECT @LatestDate = MIN([Date]) FROM DimDate
WHERE [Date] >= @LatestDate
AND IsWeekday = 1 AND IsHoliday = 0

PRINT @LatestDate
```

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer; most of the content that you are asking the OP to use as a solution is on another website.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I took out all the USA Holidays columns and dates and it does the job...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider here:

Use the line

```
Set Dateformat dmy;
```

To ensure the string conversion to date is in the correct date format (in this case non-American).

Ensure (1,7) are the correct weekend dates for the specific server.  You can test this by running:

```
Select @@Datefirst
```

Which will tell you what day of the week is the first.  The default is 7 (Sunday), which works for the example below.  You can change this if necessary:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181598.aspx

This is something to be aware of if you plan to port the code to another server.

Your code should add 1 for a Sunday and 2 for a Saturday:

```
-- Saturday
if datepart(dw,@LatestDate) = (1)
    set @LatestDate = DATEADD(dd,1,@LatestDate);

-- Sunday
if datepart(dw,@LatestDate) = (7)
    set @LatestDate = DATEADD(dd,2,@LatestDate);
```

Using a date dimension, whilst adding a little initial overhead is easier, more efficient and also more robust (i.e. @@Datefirst independent).  You can also easily populate public holidays and take these into account.  There are many scripts out there to populate a date dimension table, for example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho